# The number "1" is being inserted in my website with no apparent reason

Tags: php, html

The number "1" is being inserted in my website while it hasn't been implemented by me.

I am currently using a template.php file to handle all the creation of pages where I only need to import the code for the content to a $the_content variable and then print it.

I am also using a custom function to print this code, it is kept in a php variable and since I need to print php code and I'm unable to do that with the echo function I just had to. This is inserted between the content and the footer:

[image: HTML]

I don't know why this is happening, I've checked all the code for a possible mistake from me but it is being implemented once the page is rendered.

Template file (template.php):

```
<?php
function betterEval($code) {
    $tmp = tmpfile ();
    $tmpf = stream_get_meta_data ( $tmp );
    $tmpf = $tmpf ['uri'];
    fwrite ( $tmp, $code );
    $ret = include ($tmpf);
    fclose ( $tmp );
    return $ret;
}

?>
<html lang="zxx">
        <head>
            <?php  include 'head.php' ?>
        </head>
        <body>
            <?php require 'navbar.php';?> <!-- Tem de estar dentro de <nav></nav> -->       
            <?php echo betterEval($the_content); ?> <!-- Tem de estar dentro de <main></main> -->         
            <?php require 'footer.php'; ?>  <!-- Tem de estar dentro de <footer></footer> -->
        </body>
</html>
```

Home Page (index.php):

```
<?php
    $the_content = '<section class="banner-area">       
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row fullscreen align-items-center justify-content-between">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 banner-content">
                            <h6 class="text-white">O website número 1 em</h6>
                            <h1 class="text-white">Revisão de Suplementos</h1>
                            <p class="text-white">
                                X Reviews verifica quais são os melhores Suplementos disponíveis no mercado de forma a permitir o utilizador
                                fazer uma escolha mais consciente antes de realizar a compra.
                            </p>
                            <a href="menu.php" class="primary-btn text-uppercase">Comece a pesquisar</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </section>
            <!-- End banner Area -->

            <!-- Start home-about Area -->
            <section class="home-about-area section-gap">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 home-about-left">
                            <h1>O que fazemos?</h1>
                            <p>
                                Nós avaliamos diferentes tipos de Suplementos e outros produtos através de diversas categorias de forma a determinar os produtos de melhor qualidade
                                permitindo assim o utilizador final fazer uma decisão mais consciente no momento da compra.
                            </p>
                            <a href="about.php" class="genric-btn primary-border circle arrow">Ler mais<span class="lnr lnr-arrow-right"></span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 home-about-right">
                            <div class="single-service">
                            <div class="thumb">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="img/about-img.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </section>

            <?php
                include ("categorias-pesquisa.php");
                include ("requisicao-produto.php");
            ?>';
?>

<?php include 'template.php'; ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo betterEval($the_content); ?>` <-- you don't want the echo there, that's essentially going to echo the return value, which will be `true` if the include succeeds - and therefore prints `1`

Comment: `$ret = include ($tmpf);` then `return $ret`, makes `return 1` if the include was successful.  `include` returns 1 on successfull include. You then print it to the page by doing `echo $ret = include ($tmpf);`, so this behavior is as expected.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks for the quick help, I already have gotten rid of the 1 that's being printed. Meanwhile after calling the betterEval function and then echoing $the_content the content is getting inserted twice. Any ideas why?

Comment: @CD001 Yeah, that's right, what happens now is that my content is getting printed twice. I'll see if I can find a solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks @Qirel and @CD001 I already fixed it, I just removed the ```return $ret; ``` (What was causing the function to return the 1) and kept the code like before ```echo betterEval($the_content);```

Comment: OMG... **better**EVAL?

Comment: I'd love to see a justification of how that function is "better" than a plain `eval`; it certainly doesn't remove any of the security implications. Maybe it's real purpose is `workAroundBlockOnUseOfEval`?

Comment: @IMSoP **UNLIKE** normal eval(), betterEval() follows normal php opening and closing tag conventions, and it always throws a ParseError if there was a parse error, instead of returning false (note: this was fixed for normal eval() in php 7.0, but point is still valid for PHP 5.6), and unlike normal eval(), it generates sane exception backtraces (idk if this is fixed in 7 or not, but at least this was the case in php5)

Comment: @SalmanA **UNLIKE** normal eval(), betterEval() follows normal php opening and closing tag conventions, and it always throws a ParseError if there was a parse error, instead of returning false (note: this was fixed for normal eval() in php 7.0, but point is still valid for PHP 5.6), and unlike normal eval(), it generates sane exception backtraces (idk if this is fixed in 7 or not, but at least this was the case in php5)

Comment: @hanshenrik how does a **better**Eval protect you from doing `betterEval('<?php unlink("C:\\windows"); ?>');`?

Comment: @SalmanA it doesn't. it's not a security-enhanced eval. it's better for the reasons i stated above. if it was a security-enhanced eval, it would probably be named `sandboxedEval();`. (btw you can't run unlink() on a directory, you have to use rmdir() for that. but if you're looking for a critical file to unlink(), check `C:\windows\system32\hal.dll`, windows can't boot without it, but because nothing is using it post-boot, ntfs still allows the file's deletion post-boot, no program is having any open file handles to the file. still need to get past `Windows Resource Protection` tho)

Comment: @hanshenrik Thanks. I pray I'll never need it, but I can see that if you have one of the very few values use cases for eval in the first place, the error handling improvements could be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, betterEval() returns 1. it does not return a string, it just generates output directly, so replace

```
<?php echo betterEval($the_content); ?>
```

with

```
<?php betterEval($the_content); ?>
```

and the 1 should be gone.

Comment: I just noticed that you're the author of that code snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

Here betterEval() function return the integer value (1) in $ret variable. So You can get it directly without echo.

replace this :

```
<?php echo betterEval($the_content); ?>
```

to

```
<?php betterEval($the_content); ?>
```